# Split PDF form into pages preserving fields

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to split a multipage AcroForms into singe pages AcroForm but I'm not able to 'preserve' the complete functionality of the form:

This's the code I'm using:

```
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(options.InputFile))
        {
            string basename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(options.InputFile);

            for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pagenumber++)
            {
                string filename;
                Document document;
                PdfCopy copy;

                document = new Document();

                filename = String.Format("{0}.{1}.pdf", basename, pagenumber);

                copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

                document.Open();

                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber));

                document.Close();
            }

            return reader.NumberOfPages;
        }
```

The resulting pdf pages behave as fully working AcroForm (when used trough Acrobat Reader) but if I try to 'list' the fields inside each one of them trough iTextSharp I cannot find a single field...

P.S. I found an online service that split the form 'correctly'. Many software (PDF Split and Merge Basic for examle) behave like mine.

Where I'm wrong?

Best regards,
 Mike

Comment: I found some references to `CopyAcroForm` and `CopyDocumentFields` but they are related to the whole document and thus cannot be invoked on the single page.

Comment: You need to use the `setMergeFields()` method as demonstrated in the following example: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thks @Bruno the solution is this one. N.B. I had to reinstantiate the reader for each page since using copy.AddDocument(reader, pages) removes all pages from reader object.

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(options.InputFile);
        List<int> pages;
        pages = new List<int>();

        int n_pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

        string basename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(options.InputFile);

        for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= n_pages; pagenumber++)
        {
            using (PdfReader page_reader = new PdfReader(options.InputFile))
            {
                string filename;
                Document document;
                PdfCopy copy;

                pages.Clear();

                filename = String.Format("{0}.{1}.pdf", basename, pagenumber);

                document = new Document();

                copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

                copy.SetMergeFields();

                document.Open();

                pages.Add(pagenumber);

                copy.AddDocument(page_reader, pages);

                document.Close();
            }
        }

        return n_pages;
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you for porting the example from Java to C#. This is very useful for further reference.

Comment: I think this's the scope of this site indeed.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie the it's a normal behaviour for the `copy.AddDocument(page_reader, pages);` to remove all pages from `page_reader` ?

Comment: If you pass a `pages` parameter, you are using the equivalent of `PdfReader.SelectPages()`, so yes, you should not reuse `page_reader` when you've used `copy.AddDocument(page_reader, pages)`. Either create a new `PdfReader` at each time, or use `PdfImportedPage` objects to add specific pages.